# Print_r equivalent in Liquid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid, shopify

In Liquid, how can I find out all the values that a collection contains? Is there a `print_r` function or similar?

The example below will return the item title, but I would like to know what other variables item also holds.

```
item.title
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've no experience with liquid per se, which is why I can't post this as an answer, but you can use `inspect` in Ruby to print the contents of an object: http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/inspect .

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ah got there in the end! Not quite a print_r, but near enough to see whats available. This prints out the properties in JSON format, so you can see whats in there.

```
{{item | json}}
```

Comment: Note that not all available Liquid attributes will get dumped with the ` | json` filter - the structure of the objects may be different in some cases!  Shopify's [Liquid reference](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects) is a great resource should anything not quite behave the way you expect (or if you're looking for something that should be there but doesn't seem to be)

Comment: Important point by Dave. For example a Shopify image might show as just the URL in the JSON, but in reality it's a Shopify object that includes properties like `.src`, and `.alt`